# Service Cloud not able to configure in CPQ

Tags: cpq, service

Actually, I'm facing one problem last few days, I have opened an Sfdc cpq trailhead org for three months. But there I want to enable Service contract for cpq. I have already followed a few steps from salesforce cpq guide no changes found can anybody please help me out??

1. I have already enabled entitlement. (Done)
2. as per sfdc doc after enabling entitlement, Contract will change to Service contract and Subscription will change to contract line item. (Not happen)
3. I have seen one SFDC video, when they create a contract from quote then and then one entitle is created (How to do that)?

Video Link: https://www.salesforce.com/video/297195​​​

Comment: pls provide link to sfdc doc for #2

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_service_cloud_parent.htm&type=5